# When do i Use Images and when do I create forms with css3

Tags: image, css

Recently I have heard that you can create forms like a rectangle for example with css3, but i wonder why would I ever do that, doesnt it only cost more time in comparison to images?

I can only imagine that it would be better for pageload speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now to be clear of few things... Images and CSS are two different things.

Speaking about form, if you want a rectangle, then you can just have some tags like div tag, and style them using CSS.

CSS is way faster than loading few images. If u wanna use images for designing purpose such as creating a rectangle, then its better to use CSS to get the effect.

Gone are those days when people used to use image to style up the website. CSS are ruling now. Unless its an album thing, or slider, or background image, or profile image, etc don't use image for designing purpose.

Also, with CSS along with few tags, you can create few geometrical objects like arrows, circle, rectangle, squares, etc.

**Speaking about time, being a developer, you have to look at the TIME COST from clients prospective always, than developers prospective. Things can be get done in a jiffy, and unorganized manner, but comes in huge cost.**